# generic parent class as a polymorphic variable in a list

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a generic parent class as a polymorphic variable in a list.

My terminology here may not be correct, so bellow is some code that outlines essentially what i'm trying to do.

```
abstract class parent<T>
{
     private T var;
     abstract T evaluate();
}
class child1 extends parent<Integer>
{
     Integer evaluate() { return var; }
}
class child2 extends parent<Boolean>
{
     Boolean evaluate() { return var; }
}

ArrayList<parent>  list1 = new ArrayList<parent>();
list1.add(new child1());
list1.add(new child2());

for(parent list_item : list1) { list_item.evaluate(); }
```

I understand that this may not be possible, any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is unclear. Exactly what are you trying to do? I don't see the declaration (abstract or concrete) of the `evaluate()` method anywhere.

Comment: Could someone explain `ArrayList<parent>` to me? I don't see `parent`s type parameter `T` in there...

Comment: That's the part i'm stuck on. I would like parent to hold both child1 and child2, which are integer and boolean respectively, so i'm not sure what type parameter it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using raw types.  Use a wildcard instead:

```
ArrayList<parent<?>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(new child1());
list1.add(new child2());
```